# Installing Ubuntu Server on a Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

If I install Ubuntu Server Version on a Oracle Virtual Box in Windows XP will I be able to access the ubuntu server from outside the windows xp using a SSH tool like putty and Win-Scp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VirtualBox installs a virtual network adapter when you install it.  Set your networking to "Bridged Adapter", then from the dropdown, pick whichever network adapter is connected to your router, and start the VM.  The guest OS will obtain its own IP address, which you can see by using `ifconfig` in Ubuntu.  That's the IP you'll use for any connections to that VM.

I'd recommend setting a static IP either in the VM or on your router/DHCP server if you'll have services running on your VM.